# How can I make Ctrl+Q quit a QT5 app with no menubar

Tags: c++, qt, exit, kde-plasma

I'm working on a KDE app written in QT5 that has no menubar and no visible quit button. I'd like to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> quit the app without having to bind the action to a user-visible GUI element. I'm having trouble getting using `QAction` for this:

```
    // Allow Ctrl+Q to quit the app
    QAction *actionQuit = KStandardAction::quit(QApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()), this);
    actionQuit->setShortcut(QKeySequence(QKeySequence::Quit));
```

Doesn't work, obviously. What am I doing wrong, and/or if this approach is wrong, what's the sanest way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `actionQuit` to a widget, in order to make it listen to key events. Assuming that `this` is your widget:

```
addAction(actionQuit);
```

Furthermore, you may want to set the action's shortcut context to `QApplicationShortcut`, to make it application wide, e.g.

```
actionQuit->setShortcutContext(QApplicationShortcut);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!